# Sync between two controller

Tags: embedded

Using 2 MM9z_639 controller for SPI master and SPI slave.

In datasheet it mentioned as when it configured as Master,clock should be bus clock/2, when it configured as Slave, clock should be bus clock/4

So I decided to keep bus clock /4, to ensure both controllers are running on same time.  I am using bus clock as 28Mhz.

Initially mater will send character 'R'.Slave will reply with 'R'. Then both will start executing their code.

To verify sync, I enabled 500ms timer. Every 500ms tone counter will increment both sides.

For every one sec master will ask counter value of slave and also stores its count value.  If both counter are same then both are in sync.

But problem is:

in master = 2,4,6,8,...

from slave = 0,0,2,4

Initially two bytes getting 0.

Then I decided to send some dummy data from slave to master whenever interrupt hits. In this condition I am getting proper value.

Also I checked both are running on same speed.

Please find the code for SPI.
I am using controller **MM9Z1_639** NXP

Here am doing sync between two controller so that both controller should start reading adc channel at same time. For that one first i send char 'a' from master to slave and slave will replay back with 'r'.Then on wards both code will start reading adc channel.
Parallel am starting 500ms timer to increase count. And reading both Master and slave count every  1 sec.

```
void Init(void)
{


    /* SPICR1 register configuration */
    SPICR1_SPE = 1U;
    SPICR1_LSBFE = 0U;
    SPICR1_CPHA = 1U;
    SPICR1_CPOL = 0U;


#ifdef MICRO1
    SPICR1_MSTR = 1U;

    SPICR1_SSOE = 0U;
    SPICR1_SPIE = 0U;
    SPICR1_SPTIE = 0U;
#endif

#ifdef MICRO2
    SPICR1_MSTR = 0U;
    SPICR1_SSOE = 0U;
    SPICR1_SPIE = 1U;
    SPICR1_SPTIE = 1U;  
#endif

    /*SPICR2 register configuration */

    SPICR2_XFRW = 0U; /* 8 bit data transfer */
    SPICR2_SPC0 = 0U;
    SPICR2_BIDIROE = 0U;


#ifdef MICRO1
    SPICR2_MODFEN = 0U;

    SPICR2_SPISWAI = 1U;
#endif

#ifdef MICRO1
    SPICR2_MODFEN = 0U;
#endif

    /*SPIBR configuration */
    SPIBR = 0x01;

T_UBYTE Spi_ASample_Tx_Buf_Index = 0;
T_FLAG Spi_ASample_Sync_data;
T_UBYTE Rx_Count = 0;
static T_UBYTE counter =0x03;
static T_UBYTE call =0x00;
static T_UBYTE status_timer =0;

void ISR_FCT Spi_ASample_ISR(void)
{


#ifdef MICRO2
    if (SPISR_SPTEF)
    {
        (void)bspi_GetRxData();
        if(status_timer==1)
        {
        SPIDRL='r';
        status_timer=3;



        }
        else if(status_timer==0)
        {
            SPIDRL='A';
        }
        else
        {
            SPIDRL=ADC_sync_time();

        }
        if (Rx_Count < 7)
            Rx_Count++;
        else
            Rx_Count = 0;
    }
#endif

}


void start_ADC_Sync_time()
{
    if(status_timer>0)
    {
    call=(call+1);
    }
}

T_UBYTE ADC_sync_time(void)
{

return call;
}


void set_flag(void)
{
    status_timer=1;
}
```

Comment: The question makes little sense; the master clocks the slave - it is not possible to get out of sync.  What is a "MM9z_639" - be more specific about the part you are using - exact mart number and manufacturer, a link to the data sheet perhaps  The only mention of this name on the entire internet appears to be just this question!

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, it seems that your method used to "verify the sync" (whatever than might mean in this context) is flawed; without seeing the code it is hard to see both what you are trying to do and why it is wrong.  But instinct is that it is also unnecessary.  Also you cannot send dummy data from a slave, the master has to poll it by sending data. Data is output from the slave as as a result of receiving data from the master - the master is in control; the clue is in the name.

Comment: Definitely _unclear what you are asking_, but giving you a chance to fix the question before voting to close.

Comment: If the master is using different clock polarity or clock phase than the slave, bad things will happen. That's the first thing to check when trouble-shooting SPI.

Comment: While the bus master clocks the SPI *bus* the SPI *interface* in most MCUs must be internally clocked *regardless of role*.  If operating at a device it *samples* the SPI bus clock and the data at corresponding times, and must typically *oversample* it to work correctly.   That's different than many peripheral chips which are actually clocked by the SPI clock.   As for the question asked, it's quite unclear but it seems like there's probably an unfounded expectation.